# Is there somewhere I can write my name on iPod touch, for if I lost it?

Tags: ipod-touch

Where in my iPod Touch I can write my name and phone number, so if I lost it or it been stolen and found by the police (as I read that happened), someone could call me to go get it back?

Comment: Ummm http://cl.ly/4WL8 ? Like, you know, 50% of the device?

Comment: @joshhunt I prefer do it without make it ugly..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, but you can create an image that has your name and contact info on it, then use that as your lock screen wallpaper.

You could also create a note on the device or an "emergency/lost" contact in the address book, but both of those require you to *not* use a passcode to use the device. A wallpaper with contact info works even if the person who finds your iPod can't unlock it.

Comment: Great, I used the wallpaper for the lock screen, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are really fussed about this then you can go to an engraver and get your name and phone number engraved on the back.

Comment: I don't recommend this for two reasons: First, it will void any warranty you may have. Second, etching an iPod touch after it's assembled can itself damage the internals. When Apple etches them for you, they etch the back panel before assembly.

Answer (score 2):

You can also install Find My iPod Touch if you have a 4th gen iPod Touch. I'm not sure if it works on earlier models, but it might.

[Apple's page on Find My iPod Touch](http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/features/find-my-ipodtouch.html)

Comment: It won't work on earlier models.

Comment: I think it does work on the older models if you _also_ have the latest model (iPad, iPhone 4 or 4th gen iPod Touch). You can register the new device to get the free Find My iDevice account then register other devices on that account.

Answer (score 1):

I put a sticker on back containing my work contact information in large print.  Easy to read even if the batteries are dead.